# build-spec Error parsing spec file: expected value at line 1 column 1

Tags: substrate

I am following the Substrate Developer Hub tutorial in here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/customspec

I have successfully executed the command:
**./target/release/node-template build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain local > customSpec.json**

But when I try to parse this last file using this command:
**./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json**

I got the following error:
**Error: Input("Error parsing spec file: expected value at line 1 column 1")**

The contents of the customSpec.json are:

```
{
  "name": "Local Testnet",
  "id": "local_testnet",
  "chainType": "Local",
  "bootNodes": [],
  "telemetryEndpoints": null,
  "protocolId": null,
  "properties": null,
  "consensusEngine": null,
  "lightSyncState": null,
  "genesis": {
    "runtime": {
      "frameSystem":
...
...
"palletSudo": {
        "key": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am attempting the Hello World Hackathon by Polkadot.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is the [second such report](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/40) I have heard. Are you building on Windows by any chance?

Comment: Hello Dan, yes I am building in Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is even related to Windows...if you check out the Issue I linked above you'll see that one of my colleagues is able to use Windows w/o problems. My only suggestion at this time would be to try using Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: Wouldn't the issue be related to the compiler trying to read the .json file? Is this the Rust environment? The setup to use the node template is quite lengthy I might have done something wrong in the process, but not only me is having this issue so perhaps is something outdated in the tutorial to set up the node template?

Comment: Do you know which exact components do I have to install using the Visual Studio Installer? That part of the tutorial is not well explained.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem may have something to do with Windows-style line endings. If you can verify that the node generates the JSON file, I would expect it to be able to convert that to a raw chain spec without any problem...as long as that JSON file wasn't modified. Did you open the file in a text editor before trying to convert it to a raw spec? If so, it's possible that your text editor may have converted the line endings for you. Can you try generating the JSON file and then the raw chain spec back-to-back without even so much as opening the JSON file in between?

Comment: Have you try compressing the JSON file? That will eliminate all the `\r\n`. https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/json-minifier.html

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem on when I was building the chain spec using Windows Powershell. But I used the regular Windows Console and it worked fine.